# building a kernel module using CMake

Tags: cmake, compilation, kernel-module

I want to build a linux kernel driver which uses another library which can be compiled to be used with kernel code.
I tried using Makefile and adding all the sources/headers with no luck.

The recommended way is to use CMake but I didn't find any good tutorial on how to use CMake with linux kernel module.

Are there some basic rules?
An hello world example?

Comment: There is **no standard way** for use CMake with the Linux kernel modules. Yes, you may adapt CMake for doing so (in fact, I have done that in the past), but this implies writing many helper macros, functions and other "sugar", which is far beyond the Stack Overflow question/answer format. In any case, when you want to build a single module from 1 or 2 files, using Makefile is much more simpler.