# How do I set up VSC with CMake and clangd to do intellisense with Linux Kernel dev?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, cmake, linux-kernel, intellisense

I'm attempting to develop a kernel driver using visual studio code on Linux.
For syntax highlighting I'm used to using clangd with cmake.

I tried to set up a cmake file for kernel dev, but I'm not able to get it to work.
As for now I'm just using a simple makefile.

```
obj-m += src/*.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

This solution is fine, but this means that I have no intellisense. How can I set up intellisense for Linux kernel dev?

Comment: You might be out of luck based on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54891622/building-a-kernel-module-using-cmake, at least if you need cmake

Comment: Another solution is fine as long as I get some sort of intellisense. For now everything is red, but compiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution.
After looking at the [clangd installation documentation](https://clangd.llvm.org/installation.html), it was described;

For a make-based build, you can run `make clean; bear -- make` to generate the file (and run a clean build!).

After making my makefile like below and running the command above. Visual Studio Code + clangd was able to resolve the intellisense by itself.

```
obj-m += Driver.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```